# php правильно вычесть сколько осталось дней

Tags: php, дата, datetime

помогите сиротке.
Вопрос в том что нужно **правильно** вывести сколько осталось дней.
Есть **дата окончания** в формате unix которую я вывожу как обычно:
`date('d.m.Y', $vip['expires']);`
формат `d.m.Y` меня не устраивает и я хочу чтобы просто выводилось сколько осталось дней до окончания. то есть надо помимо всего еще учесть количество дней в текущем месяце

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос кодом, с которым у Вас возникли проблемы. Спасибо.

Comment: echo date('d.m.Y', $vip['expires']);